# Do I need to add WDS Driver Packages to an install image?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, wds

Do I need to add my driver packages to my Windows 7 install image in order for them to get deployed when using that install image?

I can't seem to understand if this is necessary based on the documentation. The documentation sort of makes it sound like all I need to do is add it to the driver group and set the filters on the driver group appropriately...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to manually add drivers to the install image, simply add them to the WDS drivers node. WDS will use Plug and Play to choose the correct driver to install. You can limit which drivers are available to your images by setting up driver groups and have the entire group installed to the client, or to use filters to define which clients get access to which driver groups.
The TechNet article ‘[Managing and Deploying Driver Packages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348456(v=ws.10).aspx)’ explains these methods in more detail.

More articles and videos related to deploying Windows can be found on the [Deliver and Deploy Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) (and [Windows 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh974336)) pages of the Springboard Series on TechNet.

Hope this helps,